# Environment that detects if it contains a given command/string

Tags: environments, conditionals, amsthm

I defined an environment that center and box a content.

```
\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
\newenvironment{result}[1][\textwidth]
{
\begin{center} %The box will be centered
\begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
\begin{varwidth}{#1} %Minipage that set its width to the text width it contains
\begin{center} %The text will be centered
}
{
\end{center}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\end{center}
}
```

If I use the `\qedhere` command in the environment, it will naturally box the qed symbol. My idea is to find a way to have an environment that detects if it contains the `\qedhere` command. If it does contain the command, then it will execute a given code (in this case, it would delete the string then rewrite it outsite the fbox environment but inside the last center environment in order to place the tombstone next right to the box). It it does not contain it, then it executes another code (in this case it would be the usual code in the body).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,amsthm}

\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
\newenvironment{result}[1][\textwidth]
{
\begin{center} %The box will be centered
\begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
\begin{varwidth}{#1} %Minipage that set its width to the text width it contains
\begin{center} %The text will be centered
}
{
\end{center}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\end{center}
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%It redefines the qed command to delete the hfill
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak
    \, \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
\newenvironment{proof2}
{\begin{proof} \leavevmode \par \nobreak}
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\triangleleft$} \end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result \qedhere
\end{result}  
\end{proof2}
\end{document}
```

=================================================

Reply for Peter Grill

I wrote this

```
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{result}[1][\textwidth]{%
    \StrPosition{\BODY}{\qedhere}[\@Position]%
    \IfEq{\@Position}{0}{%
        % Does not contain \qedhere
        \begin{center} 
        \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} 
        \begin{varwidth}{#1} 
        \begin{center} 
            \BODY
        \end{center}
        \end{varwidth}
        \end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
        \end{center}
    }{%
        %% Does contain \qedhere
        \begin{center} 
        \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} 
        \begin{varwidth}{#1} 
        \begin{center} 
            \BODY
        \end{center}
        \end{varwidth}
        \end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
        \qedhere
        \end{center}
    }%
}%
\makeatother
```

but it did not display anything, so I just replaced by `$\triangleleft$` and it does the work. Now the issue is that `\qedhere` still remains in the `\BODY`

[image]

Comment: you could use a boolean that you set to false at the begin of the environment, and that \qed then sets (globally) to true. See e.g. the etoolbox package.

Comment: `\let\qedhere \relax\BODY`   in the branch where you want it to do nothing

Comment: Your question could use some elaboration.  Apparently, not only do you want to determine if the environment body has a particular control sequence, but you wish to alter the body in different ways (if it does or if it doesn't).  It would be helpful to know exactly the alterations you seek depending on the particular condition.

Comment: My goal is to make the `\qedhere` command working with my environment.
(My environment is centering a text in a modified minipage that scales with text, then boxing it, then centering again)
 If I write `\qedhere` in the body, it will place the tombstone inside the boxed environment. What I want, is to move the `\qedhere`, so if I write it in the `\BODY`, I want the environment to delete the string and rewrite it outside the boxed environment (so it would be just next right the box)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It deletes the definition of `\quedhere` and thus puts the tombstone back at the bottom. 
This code does the job `\def\qedsymbol{\hspace{-5pt}} \BODY`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use the `environ` pacakge with which give you access to `\BODY` which contains the body of the environment. You can then check if `\BODY` contains `\qedhere` and then invoke a different environment.

Below I define two environments `{WithQedHere}` and `{WithoutQedHere}`. The `{result}` environment uses `\StrPosition` to determine the postion of the `\qedhere`.  If `\@Position` is `0`, the the string is not in the `\BODY`, otherwise the `\BODY` contains an occurance of `\qedhere`:

[image]

If there are problems with this approach, an alternative would be to modify `\qedhere` to set a boolean flag to true. Typeset the `\BODY` into a box and then check the value of the boolean flag and make the appropriate switch. This may require typsetting the content twice though.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}


\newenvironment{WithQedHere}{%
    \par Using  \textbf{WithQedHere} environment\par%
}{%
}%
\newenvironment{WithoutQedHere}{%
    \par Using \textbf{WithoutQedHere} environment\par%
}{%
}%

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{result}{%
    \StrPosition{\BODY}{\qedhere}[\@Position]%
    \IfEq{\@Position}{0}{%
        %% Does not contain \qedhere
        \begin{WithoutQedHere}
            \BODY
        \end{WithoutQedHere}
    }{%
        %% Does contain \qedhere
        \begin{WithQedHere}
            \BODY
        \end{WithQedHere}
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\newenvironment{proof2}
{\begin{proof} \leavevmode \par \nobreak}
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\triangleleft$} \end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result \qedhere
\end{result}  
\end{proof2}

\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result.
\end{result}  
\end{proof2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't put a too long reply here, I edited my post.

Comment: @Flowt: If you don't want the `\qedhere` you can just redefine it `\def\qedhere{}` ()within a group so it does not make this change for all futher cases of your document.

Comment: It deletes the definition of `\quedhere` and thus puts the tombstone back at the bottom. 
This code does the job `\def\qedsymbol{\hspace{-5pt}} \BODY`

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use `xstring`, because it can do nasty things (it tries to fully expand the arguments).

I'd rather use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` to grab the contents of the environment, locally make `\qedhere` into a no-op and add it after the `\fbox` if present in the body.

Note that I move to the proper place the `\renewcommand` for changing the QED symbol. I also use `[b]` for the `varwidth` in order to place the QED symbol at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,amsthm}

\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{result}{O{\textwidth}+b}
 {
  \begin{center} %The box will be centered
  \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
  \begin{varwidth}[b]{#1} %Minipage that set its width to the text width it contains
    \centering %The text will be centered
    % make \qedhere a noop
    \cs_set_eq:NN \qedhere \prg_do_nothing:
    #2
  \end{varwidth}
  \end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
  % add \qedhere if present in the body
  \regex_match:nnT { \c{qedhere} } { #2 } { \qedhere }
  \end{center}
 }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%It redefines the qed command to delete the hfill
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak
    \, \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
\newenvironment{proof2}
 {%
  \begin{proof}
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\triangleleft$}%
  \leavevmode\par\nobreak\noindent\ignorespaces
 }
 {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result \qedhere
\end{result}  
\end{proof2}

\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result \\
    on several \\
    lines\qedhere
\end{result}
\end{proof2}

\begin{proof2}
Hence, we have
\begin{result}
    The result
\end{result}
with some more words.
\end{proof2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One small issue `\regex_match:nnT { \c{qedhere} } { #2 } { \qedhere }` contains `_` and therefore it displays `_ must be inside math mode`

Comment: @Flowt Did you forget `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` around the definition of `result`?

Comment: No I pasted as you wrote it. It's strange because it says this only in the editor of overleaf, it is not a real error i.e. the compilator does not see any problem.

Comment: @Flowt That's something that only depends on Overleaf.